# Subset starting from specific id

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

### About the task (you can skip this part)

I'm creating pagination with so-called *infinite scroll*. 
I think it's good idea to use id of last element on a page and number of elements for pagination.
When a user scrolled to the bottom of a page, AJAX request is performed with id of the last element on a page and a limit.
Ordinary *limit+offset* is not a good idea in my case, because elements might be added quite frequently, so it can cause doubling of last elements on the page (because of an offset shifting).

### Question:

The query fetching elements from DB looks like (a simplified example):

```
SELECT 
    `id`, `name`
FROM 
    `table` 
WHERE 
    `row` = 'some stuff'
ORDER BY 
    `name`
```

The set fetched by this query is:

```
| id | name| 
|----|-----| 
| 8  |  A  |
| 3  |  B  |
| 9  |  C  |
| 2  |  D  |
| 1  |  E  |
```

And I need to fetch just a subset of element after the one with id = 3 and of two rows length (rows with id 9, 2).
How can I modify the original query to fetch this subset?

Comment: You don't give us enough info. What's the initial data look like? What original query?  Having said that in general pagination should not be done in the db.

Comment: You obviously need to have some way to order the results.  Do you have a date or order column that you can use?

Comment: user3741598, initial data is rows from a table. The original query is quite complex and can vary from page to page, so I didn't want to complicate question with it. However I tried to clarify question with more details. Thanks.

Comment: Dave, yes with there is a date column in a table, but `order by` field is varied and sometimes it isn't date. So I hope there is another way to fetch a subset =)